# OOP in python with example for cuboid class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have created a class to calculate area and perimeter of rectangle in python.

I want to expand this class and calculate area and volume of a cuboid

My try is the following

```
class Rectangle ():  
    def __init__(self, L, W):  
        self.length = L
        self.width = W

    def rect_perimeter(self):  
        return 2 * (self.length + self.width)

    def rect_area(self):  
        return self.length * self.width


class RectangularCuboid (Rectangle):  
    def __init__(self, H):  
        self.height = H
        Rectangle.__init__ (self, L, W)  

    def rect_area(self):  
        return 2 * (self.length * self.width + self.width * self.height + self.height * self.lenght)

    def rect_volume(self):  
        return self.length * self.width * self.height

RC = RectangularCuboid(30, 20, 10)
R = Rectangular(30,20)
RC.rect_area()
RC.rect_volume()
print('Rectangle Cuboid Area:', RC.rect_area(), ', Rectangle Cuboid Volume:', RC.rect_volume())
```

but I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 24, in <module>
    RC = RectangularCuboid(30, 20, 10)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what am I missing?

Comment: just change the signature of `RectangularCuboid`'s `__init__` from `def __init__(self, H)` to `def __init__(self, H, L, W)`

Comment: @Robin Zigmond  I did it but then get the following error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 25, in <module>
    RC.rect_area()
  File "C:/Users/User/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 19, in rect_area
    return 2 * (self.length * self.width + self.width * self.height + self.height * self.lenght)
AttributeError: 'RectangularCuboid' object has no attribute 'lenght'

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: `RectangularCuboid` inherits from `Rectangle` and this takes just two arguments. You are passing three arguments to `Rectangle` when you call `RectangularCuboid(20, 10, 5)`.

Comment: @betoyla, please update your question with the new attempt and the corresponding new error. Don't use the comments for that.

Comment: Apart from your technical problems, your code implies that a cuboid is a rectangle, which is nonsense from the perspective of mathematics/geometry.

Comment: in method `rect_area` you use  **lenght** , is that problem?

Comment: @RobinZigmond you are right I did a typo because I was in a harry. Thanks for time

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt My try is for python code. At this point my perspective is python not geometry

Answer (score -1):

```
class Rectangle ():  
    def __init__(self, L, W):  
        self.length = L
        self.width = W

    def rect_perimeter(self):  
        return 2 * (self.length + self.width)

    def rect_area(self):  
        return self.length * self.width


class RectangularCuboid (Rectangle):  
    def __init__(self, H,L,W):  
        self.height = H
        self.length = L
        self.width = W

    def rect_area(self):  
        return 2 * (self.length * self.width + self.width * self.height + self.height * self.length)

    def rect_volume(self):  
        return self.length * self.width * self.height


RC = RectangularCuboid(30,20, 10)

RC.rect_area()
RC.rect_volume()
print('Rectangle Cuboid Area:', RC.rect_area(), ', Rectangle Cuboid Volume:', RC.rect_volume())
```

This should work
 RectangularCuboid inherits from Rectangle but the init is overridden, so you need to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Your answer is more suitable as a comment. Please, take a minute reading ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My bad, it's fixed now

Comment: @Capie, not a requirement but you will make people around here happier if you follow [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: I'm aware of the pep8 compliance, I use it everyday, but I'm posting this from my phone.... It's hard to do it on such small device :)